# how long does it take a us citizen to get a UK tier 2 visa, after an employer has received a sponsorship ID?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, us-citizens

A business owner in the UK wants to hire me, a US citizen. He has submitted the sponsorship request, and we are eagerly awaiting a response. Assuming he is successful, how long should it take for me to get the visa once he provides the Sponsorship ID?

Comment: gov.uk provides processing time estimates, which are pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Once a certificate is issued, the process dissolves into a very standard entry clearance application.  As mentioned in comments, you can examine the [turn-around times for Americans here](https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times).

If you are in a real hurry you may be able to qualify for a premium service. They are very flexible and have premium packages up to GBP 15k, plus a lounge for your chauffeur.